# Android BLE disconnects after bonding

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing 2 Android BLE applications.  One app will serve as the peripheral role and the other app will serve as the central role.  On the peripheral app, there is one encrypted characteristic with `PROPERTY_WRITE` and `PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED`.

The central app is able to connect to the peripheral and discover its services.  The first time that central attempts to write to the encrypted characteristic, the system begins the bonding process and a dialog for entering the PIN appears.  After the PIN is entered correctly, the characteristic can be written to successfully.  If the central disconnects from the peripheral and then attempts to reconnect, a connection is briefly established but then disconnected.  The `onConnectionStateChange` callback is received on the peripheral with a status of [`STATE_CONNECTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#STATE_CONNECTED) and then immediately called again with a status of `STATE_DISCONNECTED`.

Unless I manually unpair the devices (from the Bluetooth settings) and then start the connection process again, the central is unable to connect to the peripheral.

I've tried this solution but it did not work for me.
[BLE Device Bonding Remove Automatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076641/ble-device-bonding-remove-automatically-in-android)

Both apps are running on devices with Android 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be resolved in Android 5.1.1.  Originally, I was running the peripheral app on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A with Android 5.0.2.  I switched to a Nexus 9 running 5.1.1 and 6.0.1 and did not encounter the issue described above.

Comment: This issue is still in my 5.1.1 device, but for your answer, I test my app on android 8.0, and this issue not in 8.0. So, please set min sdk to avoid this issue.