# BLE device unpaired by force when connection->data send to app->disconnection and repeat

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm testing a BLE mcu device with my android app.

The test sequence like this, (after paired)

Connection -> Send small data to the my app of android device -> Disconnection -> Connection -> Send small data...... repeat automatically.

The one cycle(Con->Send->Discon) takes 5~10secs roughly and it works fine during first 10~20 minutes.

But suddenly the paring removed by force in the Android device.

It shows "Failed to connect to bluetooth... " with android toast popup and it's really unpaired when I see the bluetooth setting screen.

I think it's not a problem of BLE device or the App.

Is there any restrictions on repetitive connection/disconnection from android bluetooth itself?

Comment: You mean the bond suddenly gets erased by itself? Have you tried another phone?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I think I just found a solution on this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076641/ble-device-bonding-remove-automatically-in-android