# BLE - First connection with app is not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I'm working with device Texas, for management of the LED, in my custom Android app. The device has enabled the pairing with a default passkey `000000`. In my code for app, I have this part of code for reading the paired of device.

```
    private void getpaireddevices(){
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size() > 0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devicesArray) {
            device.getName();
            device.getAddress();
        }
    }
}
```

In this moment, when I enable the BLE the app found the device, it connect but not works. For this to work I should exit and reconnect with my device. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if the device is already bonded. Call `removeBond()` method to clear previous bonding state.

```
device.removeBond();
```

For check bonding state of BluetoothDevice, use `getBondState()`.

Ble gatt connection success rate is different per device by device. You may need disconnect ble by hidden method, if your connection fails continuously.

Please read this:
[BLE Device Bonding Remove Automatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076641/ble-device-bonding-remove-automatically-in-android)

The method `unpairDevice()` will unpair bluetooth connection.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
        if (bt.getName().contains("String you know has to be in device name")) {
            unpairDevice(bt);
        }
}

// Function to unpair from passed in device
private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {

        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) { Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()); }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stanley, If I use this that you write...I should paired every time that I want to connect with device. Right?

Comment: @MarioCas Well, yes. Oh are you using ble gatt connection? And you want that always connected?

Comment: It seems that you need to wait until your device ready to communicate. I suggest you give some delay (maybe 3sec?) before run your code.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Sorry @Stanley Kou, I found another problem. If I test the my app with my Samsung S8 it works very well. If I test the app with another smartphone Samsung A8, I have the problem. I click connect, connect and it does not work. I go out and re-connect and asks me for another pairing. What could cause this?

Comment: @MarioCas Welcome to the Hardware world!!! Every single hardware has it's own characteristic. It may not a problem of all Samsung A8. It must be a problem of THE device. Can you change your A8 device to another A8?

Comment: No, I can't. I haven't the another A8.

Comment: I edited answer. Try ble disconnection. Or change initial delay.

Comment: How make this ?